# bash: passing params from $3 onwards to another program (say tar)

Tags: bash

let's say my script takes filenames starting from $3

e.g.

```
archive u 2342 a.txt b.png c.html d.js
archive u 2222 a.txt b.png
```

I want to zip all the files listed starting from $3 
How can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
zip archivename.zip "${@:3}"
```

Comment: this generalizes better than using shift

Answer (score 5):

The bash command `shift` is your friend.

The script `example.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
shift 3
echo $*
```

called with `example.sh 1 2 3 4 5` will output `4 5`.

Answer (score 2):

```
FIRST=$1
shift

SECOND=$1
shift

echo $FIRST
echo $SECOND
echo tar cf archive.tar "$@"
```

Input:

```
./test.sh 1 2 3 4 5
```

Output:

```
1
2
tar cf archive.tar 3 4 5
```